# Function gets called even after setting global state to prevent it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> In react funtional component -

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!referralUserSaved && referralCode && !Object.keys(user).length) {
      if (referralCode.trim().length == 4) {
        saveReferralsInstalls();
      }
    }
  }, [deviceInfo, referralCode, broadcastSubscribed, androidId, ipAddress]);
```

> Api call where global state is saved to prevent duplcate call

```
Api.post(`/tableName`, params).send((res) => {
    if (res.type !== "error") {
      setState({ referralUserSaved: true });
    }
  });
```

> I understand multiple parameters in useffect causes it to run multiple times but even after the if condition why is the api method called and duplicate data gets stored 2-3 times?
> The  `if(!referralUserSaved)` part should have prevented the duplicate calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters are probably reloading before your asynchronous function response.

Remove useless parameters or use a state guard to prevent duplicate reload.

```
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);

const saveReferralsInstalls = async () => {
  setFetching(true);
  // Your code
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (!fetching && !referralUserSaved && referralCode && !Object.keys(user).length) {
    if (referralCode.trim().length == 4) {
      saveReferralsInstalls().then(() => setFetching(false));
    }
  }
}, [deviceInfo, referralCode, broadcastSubscribed, androidId, ipAddress]);
```